# Symfony2: how to use one form for create/update like in symfony 1.x?

Tags: forms, symfony

Symfony crud generator by default create two forms, for create and update. I want to create a twig template form.html.twig with only one form for both actions, I remember symfony 1.x I did this:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('blog/'.($form->getObject()->isNew() ? 'create' : 'update').(!$form->getObject()->isNew() ? '?id='.$form->getObject()->getId() : '')) ?>" method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If object don't have `id` this is a new object.

You can check if it is a new object in template like this:
Twig:

```
action="{{ entity.id ? path('edit_url') : path('create_url')}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it the same way, you just need to provide a mechanism for checking if the entity is new. The easiest way to do that is to pass an `is_new` var to your template.